# Usage of defined with Filehandle and while Loop

Tags: perl, while-loop, filehandle

While reading a book on advanced Perl programming<sup>(1)</sup>, I came across
this code:

```
while (defined($s = <>)) {
    ...
```

Is there  any special reason for  using `defined` here? The  [documentation for
*perlop*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) says:

> In  these  loop  constructs,  the  assigned  value  (whether  assignment  is
>   automatic or  explicit) is  then tested  to see whether  it is  defined. The
>   defined test  avoids problems where  line has a  string value that  would be
>   treated as  false by Perl, for  example a `""`  or a `"0"` with  no trailing
>   newline. If  you really  mean for  such values to  terminate the  loop, they
>   should be tested for explicitly: [...]

So, would there be a corner case or  that's simply because the book is too old
and the automatic `defined` test was added in a recent Perl version?

---

(1)  *Advanced Perl  Programming, First  Edition, Sriram  Srinivasan. O'Reilly
(1997)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perl has a lot of implicit behaviors, many more than most other languages. Perl's motto is There's More Than One To Do It, and because there is so much implicit behavior, there is often More Than One Way To express the exact same thing.

> `/foo/` instead of `$_ =~ m/foo/`
>
> `$x = shift` instead of `$x = shift @_`
>
> `while (defined($_=<ARGV>))` instead of `while(<>)`
>
> etc.

Which expressions to use are largely a matter of your local coding standards and personal preference. The more explicit expressions remind the reader what is really going on under the hood. This may or may not improve the readability of the code -- that depends on how knowledgeable the audience is and whether you are using well-known idioms.

In this case, the implicit behavior is a little more complicated than it seems. Sometimes `perl` will implicitly perform a `defined(...)` test on the result of the readline operator:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'while($s=<>) { print $s }'
while (defined($s = <ARGV>)) {
    print $s;
}
-e syntax OK
```

but sometimes it won't:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'if($s=<>) { print $s }'
if ($s = <ARGV>) {
    print $s;
}
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'while(some_condition() && ($s=<>)) { print $s }'
while (some_condition() and $s = <ARGV>) {
    print $s;
}
-e syntax OK
```

Suppose that you are concerned about the corner cases that this implicit behavior is supposed to handle. Have you committed `perlop` to memory so that you understand when Perl uses this implicit behavior and when it doesn't? Do you understand the differences in this behavior between Perl v5.14 and Perl v5.6? Will the people reading your code understand?

Again, there's no right or wrong answer about when to use the more explicit expressions, but the case for using an explicit expression is stronger when the implicit behavior is more esoteric.

Comment: I also noticed that the answer to the actual question was buried in the last paragraph.

Comment: It's very clear when `/foo/` means `$_ =~ /foo/`, but it's not nearly as clear when `<>` means `defined($_ = <>)`. I don't consider them the same.

Answer (score 4):

Say you have the following file

```
4<LF>
3<LF>
2<LF>
1<LF>
0
```

(`<LF>` represents a line feed. Note the lack of newline on the last line.)

Say you use the code

```
while ($s = <>) {
   chomp;
   say $s;
}
```

If Perl didn't do anything magical, the output would be

```
4
3
2
1
```

Note the lack of `0`, since the string `0` is false. `defined` is needed in the unlikely case that

- You have a non-standard text file (missing trailing newline).
- The last line of the file consists of a single ASCII zero (0x30).

---

BUT WAIT A MINUTE! If you actually ran the above code with the above data, you would see `0` printed! What many don't know is that Perl automagically translates

```
while ($s = <>) {
```

to

```
while (defined($s = <>)) {
```

as seen here:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e'while($s=<DATA>) {}'
while (defined($s = <DATA>)) {
    ();
}
__DATA__
-e syntax OK
```

So you technically don't even need to specify `defined` in this very specific circumstance.

That said, I can't blame someone for being explicit instead of relying on Perl automagically modifying their code. After all, Perl is (necessarily) quite specific as to which code sequences it will change. Note the lack of `defined` in the following even though it's supposedly equivalent code:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e'while((), $s=<DATA>) {}'
while ((), $s = <DATA>) {
    ();
}
__DATA__
-e syntax OK
```

Answer (score -2):

```
while($line=<DATA>){
    chomp($line);
if(***defined*** $line){
    print "SEE:$line\n";
}
}
__DATA__
1
0
3
```

Try the code with defined removed and you will see the different result.

Comment: I know it will be different, but that's not the case. The question is about using `defined` inside the loop conditional.

Comment: -1 for each of not answering the question and providing non-compiling code.

Comment: Perl automagically replaces `while($line=<DATA>)` with `while(defined($line=<DATA>))`, so you're obviously talking about something different than the OP if you see something different. (See the output of `perl -MO=Deparse -e'while($line=<DATA>) {}'`)