# How to find lines containing a match between two files in perl?

Tags: perl

I'm a novice at using perl. What I want to do is compare two files. One is my index file that I am calling "temp." I am attempting to use this to search through a main file that I am calling "array." The index file has only numbers in it. There are lines in my array that have those numbers. I've been trying to find the intersection between those two files, but my code is not working. Here's what I've been trying to do.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Enter the input file:";
my $filename=<STDIN>;
open (FILE, "$filename") || die "Cannot open file: $!";
my @array=<FILE>;
close(FILE);
print "Enter the index file:";
my $temp=<STDIN>;
open (TEMP, "$temp") || die "Cannot open file: $!";
my @temp=<TEMP>;
close(TEMP);
my %seen= ();
foreach (@array) {
    $seen{$_}=1;
 }
 my @intersection=grep($seen{$_}, @temp);
 foreach (@intersection) {
    print "$_\n";
 }
```

If I can't use intersection, then what else can I do to move each line that has a match between the two files?

For those of you asking for the main file and the index file:

#### Main file:

```
 1  CP  TRT 
 ...
 14  C1  MPE 
 15  C2  MPE 
 ...
 20  CA1 MPE
```

### Index file

```
 20
 24
 22
 17
 18
 ...
```

I want to put those lines that contain one of the numbers in my index file into a new array. So using this example, only
20 CA1 MPE would be placed into a new array.
My main file and index file are both longer than what I've shown, but that hopefully gives you an idea on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Give an example line from both the index file and the main file.

Comment: Post you input data of both files and expected output.

Comment: I updated the main post with the requested info

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming something like this?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

# creating arrays instead of reading from file just for demo
# based on the assumption that your files are 1 number per line
# and no need for any particular parsing
my @array = qw/1 2 3 20 60 50 4 5 6 7/; 
my @index = qw/10 12 5 3 2/;
my @intersection = ();
my %hash1 = map{$_ => 1} @array;

foreach (@index)
{
    if (defined $hash1{$_})
    {
        push @intersection, $_;
    }
}


print Dumper(\@intersection);
```

==== Out ====

```
$VAR1 = [
      '5',
      '3',
      '2'
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- Always have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in your program. This will catch a lot of possible errors.
- Always `chomp` after reading input. Perl automatically adds `\n` to the end of lines read. `chomp` removes the `\n`.
- Learn a more *modern* form of Perl.
- Use nemonic variable names. `$temp` doesn't cut it.
- Use spaces to help make your code more readable.

You never stated the errors you were getting. I assume it has to do with the fact that the input from your main file doesn't match your index file.

I use a hash to create an index that the index file can use via `my ($index) = split /\s+/, $line;`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);


print "Input file name: ";
my $input_file = <STDIN>;
chomp $input_file;             # Chomp Input!

print "Index file name: ";
my $index_file = <STDIN>;
chomp $index_file;             # Chomp Input!

open my $input_fh, "<", $input_file;

my %hash;
while ( my $line = <$input_fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    #
    # Using split to find the item to index on
    #
    my ($index) = split /\s+/, $line;
    $hash{$index} = $line;
}
close $input_fh;

open my $index_fh, "<", $index_file;

while ( my $index = <$index_fh> ) {
    chomp $index;
    #
    # Now index can look up lines
    #
    if( exists $hash{$index} ) {
        say qq(Index: $index  Line: "$hash{$index}");
    }
    else {
        say qq(Index "$index" doesn't exist in file.);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

@ARGV = 'main_file';

open(my $fh_idx, '<', 'index_file');
chomp(my @idx = <$fh_idx>);
close($fh_idx);

while (defined(my $r = <>)) {
    print $r if grep { $r =~ /^[ \t]*$_/ } @idx;
}
```

You may wish to replace those hardcoded file names for `<STDIN>`.

FYI: The `defined` call inside a while condition might be "[optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621221/usage-of-defined-with-filehandle-and-while-loop)".